# Executing a program in C

Tags: c, fork, stdout, stdin

At some point of my program, I'd like to run another program (which is getting parameters from stdin), with paramaters I have prepared in a text file. Then, I'd like to write the program's output into another file.

I'm new to linux, fork, and such. Tried breaking my head for HOURS without success.
I read that I should associate my input file with stdin and output file with stdout, something like that.

This is the code I wrote:

```
//move on all sub-directories .....
while((indir=readdir(dir))!=NULL)
{
    pid_t pid;
    DIR *currDir;
    struct dirent *cfile;
    char *fullpath, *outpath, *outputpath;

    //ignore hidden files
    if(indir->d_name[0]=='.')
        continue;

    //create the full path of c file
    fullpath=(char*)calloc(strlen(dirpath)+strlen(indir->d_name)+1,sizeof(char));
    strcpy(fullpath,dirpath);
    fullpath=strcat(fullpath,indir->d_name);
    fullpath=strcat(fullpath,"/");
    //open current directory
    currDir=opendir(fullpath);
    //get the c file, ignore hidden files
    while((cfile=readdir(currDir))!=NULL)
    {
        if(cfile->d_name[0]!='.')
            break;
    }
    /*compile c file*/

    //child process
    if((pid=fork())==0)
    {
        fullpath=realloc(fullpath, sizeof(char)*(strlen(fullpath)+strlen(cfile->d_name)+1));
        outpath=(char*)calloc(strlen(fullpath)+strlen(OUT_NAME)+1,sizeof(char));
        strcpy(outpath,fullpath);
        strcat(fullpath,cfile->d_name);
        strcat(outpath,OUT_NAME);
        execl("/usr/bin/gcc", "/usr/bin/gcc", "-o", outpath, fullpath,NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        wait(NULL);
    }


    //create output file path
    outputpath=calloc(strlen(fullpath)+strlen(OUTPUTFILE_NAME)+1,sizeof(char));
    strcpy(outputpath,fullpath);
    strcat(outputpath,OUTPUTFILE_NAME);

    inputpath=(char*)calloc(strlen(buff)+1,sizeof(char));
    //get input file path from buffer
    for(j=0,buffIndex++;buff[buffIndex]!='\n';buffIndex++,j++)
    {
        inputpath[j]=buff[buffIndex];
    }

////Untill here works perfectly////
    //child process
    if((pid=fork())==0)
    {
        fullpath=realloc(fullpath, sizeof(char)*(strlen(fullpath)+strlen(OUT_NAME)+1));
        strcat(fullpath, OUT_NAME);
        //re-open input file and associate it with stdin
        freopen(inputpath, "r", stdin);
        //re-open output file and associate it with stdout
        freopen(outputpath, "w", stdout);
        execl(fullpath,inputpath, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        wait(NULL);
    }

}
```

*inputpath is the full path of the file I prepared with inputs for the program.

*outputpath is the full path of a file where I want to save the program's output.

I'm definitely doing something wrong, since I get the following error:

```
/home/aviad/workspace/test/dean/input.txt~: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/home/aviad/workspace/test/jjang/fileoutput.txt: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any help?

Comment: Those look like compiler/linker errors... are you sure you're not, erm, trying to compile your .txt files somehow ...?

Comment: how? Im not calling gcc anywhere... those errors are coming right from this code.

Comment: Not sure. Post a more complete example and how you are executing your program and it might give some insight.  You didn't name your program something like `ld` by chance, did you?

Comment: The error messages are coming from `gcc` or some other program in the compiler suite asked to compile a `.txt` file, whether you have called it or not.

Comment: In addition to the problem with passing files to the linker, `freopen` isn't guaranteed to adjust the underlying file descriptor, which is what matters for `exec`.  It may only change the `stdin` and `stdout` `FILE *` objects.  You want to open the files first (with either `open` or with `fopen` and then get the file descriptor with `fileno`) and then use `dup2` instead of `freopen`.

Comment: Try putting the slash *between* the path and the filename. (I'd suggest creating a separate function for path construction, or use snprintf() for it) Also: printf() is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not enough information in your post to confirm, but I suspect you are being bitten by choosing the same name as a build tool, e.g. `ld`, for your program's name. If you do so and run

```
ld 1.txt 2.txt
```

there's a very good chance you are not executing *your* `ld`, but rather the GNU linker or similar (`/usr/bin/ld`). Normally system directories are searched before `.`, if `.` is in `PATH` at all. This avoids some unpleasant surprises like if you had run `ls` in a directory with a binary named `ls` in it, you probably still wanted `/bin/ls`.

This is why it's a good idea to run things in your cwd prefixed with `./`, so instead you'd say:

```
./ld 1.txt 2.txt
```

and the system `ld` would not longer be a candidate. You can determine which one will run by using `which ld` and `which ./ld`.

So, in reality you are not running your program at all.  This has bitten a few people I've known, including myself.  My first unix program was named "test" ;).

EDIT: based on the output, the name `cc` might be a better candidate than `ld`, but same idea.

EDIT:

Based on your update, it seems you are calling `gcc` after all, and by reading directory contents. There doesn't appear to be any check that the file you're compiling is even a `.c` file, are you sure that you're not calling this code in the directories where these text files live?

Comment: I do not name my program ld. I'll add some code to the question